# How to set new sites in IIS 7.5 to be .NET 4 by default

Tags: .net, iis-7, .net-framework-version

I just reinstalled Windows 7 and IIS is creating new .NET 2.0 sites by default. At one point I had it set to create .NET 4.0 sites by default - how do I set that up again?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Select the root element in the tree on the left – it contains the
   name of the server.
2. Click on the "`Change .NET Framework Version`" link on the right
   panel. You will now see the "Change .NET Framework Version" dialog.
3. Select the .NET 4.0 framework from the drop down list.
4. Click "OK"

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me was:

1. Click on "Application Pools" in the tree on the left
2. Click on "Set Application Pool Defaults..." on the right panel.
3. Set the ".NET Framework Version" to v4.0